# What is the name of this zeta function?

Tags: terminology, zeta-functions

I'm looking for literature – in particular, methods of evaluation – for zeta functions defined by the sum

$$\zeta(s,a) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(k^2+a)^s}\,.$$

I am interested in the continuation to $s=-3/2$.
It looks like the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function), except that in the denominator, we have $k^2$ instead of $k$.  Is there any work on this kind of sum?  Does this zeta function have a name?

Comment: Ok, I think this is related to the Epstein zeta function

Comment: Is my answer helpful to you? If not, please leave me some feedback so that I know how to improve it.

Comment: @Nilknarf Yes, it was helpful to some extent (upvoted); but I really need to be evaluate this thing accurately for a greater domain in $a$ and $s$.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have any literature for you, and I have no insight about the case of $s=-3/2$, but I can provide some methods for evaluation. First of all, I'd like you to recall the formula
$$\zeta(1,a)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2+a}=\frac{\pi \coth(\pi \sqrt a)}{\sqrt a}$$
This formula can be easily derived using the residue theorem, which I am just assuming that you already know how to use. If not, correct me and I will write you a short proof as soon as I can.

Now observe the following interesting and useful property of the function $\zeta$ as you have defined it. If $s\gt 0$, then
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{da}\zeta(s,a)
&= \frac{d}{da} \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(k^2+a)^s}\\
&= \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{d}{da} \frac{1}{(k^2+a)^s}\\
&= \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{-s}{(k^2+a)^{s+1}}\\
\end{align}$$
and so we have the following recurrence:
$$\zeta(s+1,a)=-\frac{1}{s}\frac{d}{da}\zeta(s,a),\space\space\space s\gt 0$$
From this recurrence, we can derive the following formulas:
$$\zeta(2,a)=\frac{\pi\coth(\pi\sqrt a)}{2a^{3/2}}+\frac{\pi^2\text{csch}^2(\pi\sqrt a)}{2a}$$
$$\zeta(3,a)=\frac{3\pi\coth(\pi \sqrt a)}{8a^{5/2}}+\frac{\pi^3\coth(\pi\sqrt a)\text{csch}^2(\pi\sqrt a)}{4a^{3/2}}+\frac{3\pi^2\text{csch}^2(\pi\sqrt a)}{8a^2}$$
I could keep going, but the algebra just keeps getting messier. So instead, I will generalize this by writing
$$\color{green}{\zeta(n,a)=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n-1)!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\frac{\pi \coth(\pi \sqrt x)}{\sqrt x}_{x=a}}$$
which holds for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and $a$ not a negative perfect square.

Comment: Could you explain why  upon differentiation over $a$ you got $s$ instead of $-s$ in the numerator of the expression under sum?

Comment: @user355705 Sorry, that was a mistake on my part. Thanks for catching it! It was supposed to be a $-s$, and I had incorporated that into my final (green) formula, but for some reason I didn't write it in the recurrence. Thanks again!